# Can I have a RPM depend on a directory?

Tags: linux, dependency-management, rpm, rhel, rpmbuild

I'm creating an RPM file (with rpmbuild) whose post-install script will create a file in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/`. To make sure that the directory already exists, I'd like to specify a dependency on a package which creates it.

Is it correct in this case to add a `Requires: /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d` line to the spec file? Or is it not allowed to depend on directories, and should I rather add a dependency on `xorg-x11-xinit` package (which appears to provide this directory on my system)?

The package is intended to work on CentOS (RHEL) 6.

Comment: have you tried it?? have you tested it?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes, I have tried it, and it works; but I'm not sure if it's _supposed_ to work and if it's officially supported, or if it only works accidentally.

Comment: centos distributions are like prehistoric brick stones... I doubt that anything will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (you can Require any path), but you should be depending on the package that provides that path. There must be a reason you are not doing this?

Comment: I just thought it would be better to depend on the directory rather than a specific package. That way, another package may provide the path as well, and theoretically the user may choose which package should be installed to satisfy this dependency. I realize that it's mostly theoretical in this case, but would like to know what's the "correct" way to express such a dependency.

Comment: The case you are talking about: two packages owning the same directory, is a packaging error, it means they would not be able to be installed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use virtual packages to avoid surprises, when the required file can be provided by more than one package.

In your example, `yum provides` says that `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d` is provided by `xorg-x11-xinit` and `qt5-qtbase-gui`, so, specifying that path as a dependency could pull a package you don expect.

You should have a virtual package for each possible package that provides the file. The package `my-xinit-x11` should contain:

```
Requires:     xorg-x11-xinit
Provides:     my-xinit
```

And your package should contain:

```
Requires:    my-xinit
```

More virtual packages can be created with the same `Provides`, so when either is installed rpmbuild will see the dependency as satisfied